# Rsync with sshpass on Linux using systemd: 'Host key verification failed.'

Tags: subprocess, rsync, systemctl, sshpass

I am trying to set up rsync with sshpass on a RaspberryPi to connect to a Synology drive in order to synchronize data.

The listed command:

```
sshpass -p 'password' rsync -avz -e 'ssh -p 22' \home\pi host@IP::home/example
```

works out fine, if I run it manually at the command prompt. As well it works out, when I implement it into a python script using the package 'subprocess':

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run([ sshpass -p 'password' rsync -avz -e 'ssh -p 22' \home\pi host@IP::home/example])
```

Whenever I want to autostart the python script using systemctl as a service, I get the following error:

> Host key verification failed.
>   rsync error: received SIGINT, SIGTERM or SIGHUP (code 20) at rsync.c(644) [sender=3.1.3]

I am wondering, what ist the difference between the command prompt and systemd in this case?

Thank you so much for your help in advance! I really appreciate every Tip!!!
Kilian

Comment: run this command and try again : `ssh-keyscan server-ip >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rude way is to add `-o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no"` to your SSH command:

```
sshpass -p 'password' rsync -avz -e 'ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" -p 22' \home\pi host@IP::home/example
```

Comment: Sorry for the reaalyy late. Thanks for your answer:) It worked out that way!!